# Basic Texture drawing with JOGL, using a Texture object

Tags: java, opengl, textures, jogl

I'm trying to give the user of my application the ability to load an image of their choice to make the background. Loading the image via Java is no problem, but I can't get the image into a texture....I just end up with a big grey box on my GLCanvas. This is the code I have so far:

```
  //if there's an image to overlay, render it
    if (renderImage) {

        gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (texture == null && img != null) {

            texture = TextureIO.newTexture(img, true);
            texture.enable();
            texture.bind();
        }

        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POLYGON);
        gl.glNormal3f(0,0,1);
            gl.glTexCoord2d(-texture.getWidth(), -texture.getHeight());
            gl.glVertex2d(-25, -25);
            gl.glTexCoord2d(-texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
            gl.glVertex2d(canvas.getWidth(),0);
            gl.glTexCoord2d(texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
            gl.glVertex2d(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            gl.glTexCoord2d(texture.getWidth(), -texture.getHeight());
            gl.glVertex2d(0, canvas.getHeight());
        gl.glEnd();
        gl.glFlush();
    }
    //otherwise, render "grass"
    else {

        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.65f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        //Clear buffer and set background color to green (the "grass" on the sides of the intersection)
        gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
```

Comment: perhaps you didn't pay attention to the title, I would like to use a Texture object to achieve this, precisely because through my days of research STARTING WITH NEHE, it seemed that was the most up to date, and simple way to texture. And since I have less than a week of experience using JOGL I found it hard to understand everything going on in NEHE, and I refuse to copy and paste code, especially if I don't understand it... but thanks for your contribution, real helpful

Comment: Also I need to accept image files that are .bmp, .png, .jpg, and .gif which the NeHe examples don't cover.

Comment: NeHe's tutorials *do* use texture objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
gl.glBegin(GL.GL_QUADS);
gl.glNormal3f(0,0,1);
gl.glTexCoord2d(0.0, 0.0);
gl.glVertex2d(0.0, 0.0);
gl.glTexCoord2d(1.0, 0.0);
gl.glVertex2d(canvas.getWidth(), 0.0);
gl.glTexCoord2d(1.0, 1.0);
gl.glVertex2d(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
gl.glTexCoord2d(0.0, 1.0);
gl.glVertex2d(0.0, canvas.getHeight());
gl.glEnd();
```

Non-repeating texture coordinates are in the 0.0 to 1.0 range by default.

Comment: that did it, geeze it was just my coordinates.....If I plug those in between my original glBegin(GL.GL_POLYGONS) it works as well. Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  Be careful going forward with `GL_POLYGON`, it only supports convex polygons.

Answer (score 1):

I put

```
  if (texture == null && img != null) {

        texture = TextureIO.newTexture(img, true);
        texture.enable();
        texture.bind();
    }
```

in a try, catch statement.